# Выделить несколько регионов при помощи API

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть ли в Yandex картах возможность средствами API выделить определенный регион по адресу? Например, "Московская область", как здесь:
https://yandex.ru/maps/geo/moskovskaya_oblast/53000044/?ll=37.674490%2C55.630423&source=wizgeo&utm_medium=maps-desktop&utm_source=serp&z=8.17

Есть модуль "Регионы", но такое ощущение, что он просто разбивает всю страну на регионы, а мне нужно именно вывести несколько определенных областей.

Answer (score 0):

Модуль подгружает регионы, нужный в которых вы можете искать простым перебором или выполнять фильтрацию удобным вам способом.

Для отображения одного единственного региона можно использовать код вида:

```
ymaps.borders.load('RU', {
    lang: 'ru',
    quality: 2
}).then(function (result) {
    // Создадим объект, в котором будут храниться коллекции с регионами.
    var districtCollections = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(null, {
            fillColor: "#0000aa", strokeColor: "000000",
            fillOpacity: 0.5, strokeOpacity: 0.5
    });

    result.features.forEach(function (feature) {
        var iso = feature.properties.iso3166;
        // Добавим субъект РФ в коллекцию.
        if (iso == 'RU-VLA'){
            districtCollections.add(new ymaps.GeoObject(feature));
        }
    });

    map.geoObjects.add(districtCollections);
})
```

Рабочий пример можно посмотреть здесь: https://jsfiddle.net/6eby7t51/