# Перекрашивание регионов при наведении мыши

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Реально ли вообще изменить цвет заливки, при наведении(или клике) на страну? Например, мышь навелась на Беларусь -> закрасилась вся страна синим, навел на РФ -> закрасилась синим и т.д. Есть какие-то eventListener (click/hover) для получаемых стран и последующее изменение параметров?
Документация скудная (чисто имхо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На базе [примера](https://jsfiddle.net/6eby7t51/) в [схожем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1345393/386299) и [примера](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/regions_districts) из песочницы Яндекса не сложно получить решение, которое вам требуется - https://jsfiddle.net/opv6mfLg/

Достаточно добавить конструкцию вида:

```
// При наведении курсора мыши будем выделять район.
districtCollections.events.add('mouseenter', function (event) {
    var district = event.get('target');
    district.options.set({
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    });
});
// При выводе курсора за пределы объекта вернем опции по умолчанию.
districtCollections.events.add('mouseleave', function (event) {
    var district = event.get('target');
        district.options.set({
            fillOpacity: 0
        });
});
```